how do i create mat expansion using angular with exact UI
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngFor="let item of autoPanel; let idx = index">
        <!-- INDEX MAPPING OF ARRAY -->
        <mat-expansion-panel class="ml-2 mr-2" style="width: -webkit-fill-available"
            (click)="getCurrentKPIName(item,idx)">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</div>

I have created dynamic mat expension using angular Img..
whenever i expand the any of the card in other side i got some space how do i remove that space.
can you please help me out of this. thanks in advance...
Exact UI what i need...

Due to the flex on the row, we cannot achieve this effect. If you are certain it's a two column layout then you need two rows, each 50% width, then run *ngFor on each of the rows. I use *ngIf="idx % 2 === 0" and the opposite condition to render the odd rows on the left side and the even ones on the right side.
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of autoPanel; let idx = index">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="idx %2 === 0">
          <mat-expansion-panel
            class="ml-2 mr-2"
            style="width: -webkit-fill-available"
          >
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title
                class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
              >
                {{ item.name }}
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <!-- INDEX MAPPING OF ARRAY -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of autoPanel; let idx = index">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="idx %2 !== 0">
          <mat-expansion-panel
            class="ml-2 mr-2"
            style="width: -webkit-fill-available"
          >
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title
                class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
              >
                {{ item.name }}
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <!-- INDEX MAPPING OF ARRAY -->
  </div>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

Alternative solution:
We can use a library called, Masonry.js to achieve these dynamic heights.
First import the necessary imports, for me it's Bootstrap and Masonry:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Basic expansion panel</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"
      async
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography mat-app-background">
    <expansion-overview-example></expansion-overview-example>
    <div style="margin-top: 24px">Current build: 18.0.2</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>

Then add the data attribute to the grid to enable Masonry for it:
<div class="row grid" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }' #masonry>

Then on the onclick event, refresh the list, using the below code:
  click(masonry: any) {
    const intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      new (window as any).Masonry('.grid', this.masonryProps).reloadItems();
    }, 10);
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef);
    }, 1000);
  }

Stackblitz Demo

This is really helpful... thanks for given your valuable time
